# Manual HMACSHA1 calculation differs from openssl results

Tags: c, openssl, hmac

I am trying to implement HMACSHA1 by Hand, to check if our serviceprovider or we calculate a wrong HMAC for a Support-Ticket (a SOAP call, hence the xml content).

The problem is, I stick to NIST Specification for HMACs and get a different result by Hand and when using openssl HMAC functions.

The following code prints:

```
B92674DCBA96F2DA93F7043071B931F5F2583FBD
4303E965D88D288C9AC594CE6C5E6AFF27D40B2D
```

while the result by openssl is the same we get in our application - so I assume, on the basis that openssl is so commonly used, that my result is wrong - but where is my error?

This is the spec I refer to:
http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.198-1.pdf

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>
#include <string.h>

#define byte unsigned char
#define IPAD 0x36
#define OPAD 0x5c
#define DIGESTSIZE 20



int main () {
    byte *derivedKey =  (byte[DIGESTSIZE]) {0x42,0xA9,0x78,0x90,0xFC,0xE5,0x16,0x8E,0x58,0x12,0x2F,0xF1,0xBA,0x32,0x5F,0x09,0x88,0x94,0x02,0x91};
    byte *content =     "<ds:SignedInfo xmlns:ds=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\" xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\"><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#\"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#\" PrefixList=\"soap\"></ec:InclusiveNamespaces></ds:CanonicalizationMethod><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1\"></ds:SignatureMethod><ds:Reference URI=\"#TS-B183A13FEB0189143115136776276601\"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#\"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#\" PrefixList=\"wsse soap\"></ec:InclusiveNamespaces></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1\"></ds:DigestMethod><ds:DigestValue>rXJdGuDqoRrUJxuGiA1eyAozifk=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo>";
    byte *oPadKey =     malloc(DIGESTSIZE);
    byte *iPadKey =     malloc(DIGESTSIZE);


    int i;
    for(i=0;i<DIGESTSIZE;i++){
        iPadKey[i]=derivedKey[i]^IPAD;
        oPadKey[i]=derivedKey[i]^OPAD;
    }

    byte *rOpInput=     malloc(strlen(content)+DIGESTSIZE);

    //concat iPad and content
    memcpy(rOpInput, iPadKey, DIGESTSIZE);
    memcpy(rOpInput+DIGESTSIZE,content,strlen(content));

    //SHA1 (iPad||content) gives the rightmost 20 bytes of the final SHA1 Input
    byte *rOp=malloc(DIGESTSIZE); // H(iPad||content)
    SHA1(rOpInput,strlen(content)+DIGESTSIZE,rOp);
    free(rOpInput);

    byte *finalInput = malloc(2*DIGESTSIZE); //oPad||H(iPad||content)

    //concat oPad and H(ipad||content)
    memcpy(finalInput, oPadKey,DIGESTSIZE);
    memcpy(finalInput+DIGESTSIZE,rOp,DIGESTSIZE);

    free(rOp);
    free(oPadKey);
    free(iPadKey);
    //SHA1(oPad||H(iPad||content))

    byte *hmac = malloc(DIGESTSIZE);
    SHA1(finalInput,40,hmac);
    free(finalInput);

    //print calculated HMAC as HEX
    for(i=0;i<DIGESTSIZE;i++){
        printf("%02X", (hmac[i] & 0xFF ));
    }
    printf("\n");


    //verify with openssl HMAC
    byte *result = HMAC(EVP_sha1(), derivedKey, DIGESTSIZE, content, strlen(content), NULL, NULL);
    for(i=0;i<DIGESTSIZE;i++){
        printf("%02X", (result[i] & 0xFF ));
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bug is *simple*. The `ipad` and `opad` need to be [**(input) block size**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithms#Comparison_of_SHA_functions) in length, not the length of the digest output. I.e. they must be 512 bits (64 bytes) for SHA-1, not 20.

I.e.

```
#define INPUT_BLOCK_SIZE 64
byte derivedKey[64] =  {0x42,0xA9,0x78,0x90,0xFC,0xE5,0x16,0x8E,0x58,0x12,
                        0x2F,0xF1,0xBA,0x32,0x5F,0x09,0x88,0x94,0x02,0x91};
// null-padded on the right
```

and then change the `DIGESTSIZE` to `INPUT_BLOCK_SIZE` for wherever the length of `ipad`, `opad` is needed.

Result:

```
4303E965D88D288C9AC594CE6C5E6AFF27D40B2D
```

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code#Definition)

> *K' is another secret key, derived from the original key K (by padding K to the right with extra zeroes to the **input block size of the hash function**, or by hashing K if it is longer than that block size)*

**(emphasis mine)**.

---

P.S. It would be better to use the `SHA1_Init`/`Update`/`Final`, as then lots of copying would be skipped. You can also avoid allocating memory for the `ipad` and `opad` separately by first calculating `ipad` and after it has been used, then xorring in place by `0x6a` to get the opad.

Comment: ahh, so i do not need to hash the key at all, as it is 24 byte long?

Comment: mainly: the java framework apache cxf/wss4j does "trim" the key it uses for hmacsha1 to 20 byte prior to calculating the HMAC - it just dropt the last 4 bytes. This is wrong in any case isn't it? The original key is 24 bytes long

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this. You can easily calculate the hash

https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Standards-and-Guidelines/documents/examples/HMAC_SHA1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

```
 #define IPAD 0x36

 #define OPAD 0x5c

 #define DIGESTSIZE 20

 #define INPUT_BLOCK_SIZE 64

 #define byte unsigned char

static byte mykey[64];

int main () {

int i;

    byte mykey[INPUT_BLOCK_SIZE] = {

0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F,
0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x1C, 0x1D, 0x1E, 0x1F, 0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27,
0x28, 0x29, 0x2A, 0x2B, 0x2C, 0x2D, 0x2E, 0x2F, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37,0x38, 0x39, 0x3A, 0x3B, 0x3C, 0x3D, 0x3E, 0x3F };

    byte content[] = {0x53, 0x61, 0x6D, 0x70, 0x6C, 0x65, 0x20, 0x6D, 0x65, 0x73,
0x73, 0x61, 0x67, 0x65, 0x20, 0x66, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x20, 0x6B, 0x65, 0x79, 0x6C, 0x65, 0x6E, 0x3D, 0x62, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x63, 0x6B, 0x6C, 0x65, 0x6E };

   byte k0_ipad_text[sizeof(content) + INPUT_BLOCK_SIZE];
   byte hmac[DIGESTSIZE];
   byte k0_opad_hash[INPUT_BLOCK_SIZE + DIGESTSIZE];

/*
 * K0 is mykey as size is 0x40 = 64 bytes
 */

    byte *oPadKey =     malloc(INPUT_BLOCK_SIZE);
    byte *iPadKey =     malloc(INPUT_BLOCK_SIZE);

     memset(oPadKey, 0, INPUT_BLOCK_SIZE);
     memset(iPadKey, 0, INPUT_BLOCK_SIZE);

    for(i=0;i<INPUT_BLOCK_SIZE;i++){
        iPadKey[i]=mykey[i]^IPAD;
        oPadKey[i]=mykey[i]^OPAD;
    }

    printf("\n iPad key = ");
    for(i=0;i<INPUT_BLOCK_SIZE;i++){
    printf("%02x ", iPadKey[i]);
    }

    printf("\n oPad key = ");
    for(i=0;i<INPUT_BLOCK_SIZE;i++){
    printf("%02x ", oPadKey[i]);
    }

//Key^ipad)||text)

    memcpy(k0_ipad_text, iPadKey, INPUT_BLOCK_SIZE);
    memcpy(k0_ipad_text + INPUT_BLOCK_SIZE, content, sizeof(content));

    SHA1(k0_ipad_text, INPUT_BLOCK_SIZE + sizeof(content), hmac);
#if 0
    printf("\n hmac  = ");
    for(i=0;i<DIGESTSIZE;i++){
    printf("%02x ", hmac[i]);
    }
#endif

    memcpy(k0_opad_hash, oPadKey, INPUT_BLOCK_SIZE);
    memcpy(k0_opad_hash + INPUT_BLOCK_SIZE, hmac, DIGESTSIZE);

    SHA1(k0_opad_hash, INPUT_BLOCK_SIZE + DIGESTSIZE, hmac);
    printf("\n hmac \n");
    for(i=0;i<DIGESTSIZE;i++){
    printf("%02x", hmac[i]);
    }

   printf("\n");

    //verify with openssl HMAC
    byte *result = HMAC(EVP_sha1(), mykey, INPUT_BLOCK_SIZE, content, sizeof(content), NULL, NULL);
    for(i=0;i<DIGESTSIZE;i++){
        printf("%02X", (result[i] & 0xFF ));
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```